# Unable to find patter in JS RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I trying to identify regular expression in JS. Expression which wrote to identify the pattern is working in Online RegEx but when i use it in my own Code it does not work. 
it says error .*|{1}/: Nothing to repeat

This is Expression -
Examples:\n.*\|{1}

Sample Data -

Examples:
|asda| asd|asd|adasda|adaasdsaasdasdsa|adsadsa|asdasdad|asdasdsd|asda |

Examples:
|Word| asd|asd|W@132|iam|GOto|asdasdad|asdasdsd|asda- |

Comment: You should use regex literal notation, `var rx = /.*\|/` or `var rx = /.*?\|/`